# Status bar and color command issues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layout

I'm following along in a tutorial and I can't really troubleshoot these two errors I am getting and I hope you can help!

The override function is giving me "Method does not override any method from its superclass" I tired removing the override and its still giving me an error, the small arrow is pointing at the p in preferredStatusBarStyle if that helps any.

The extension is giving me "Declaration is only valid at scope file" Is it called differently now?

I'm still new to programming so if this is a stupid question, Sorry.

```
  override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
            return .lightContent
        }

    extension UIColor{

        convenience init (r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) {
            self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: 1)
        }

    }
```

Comment: can you please tell us what class you are ussing for it. It should be inside a child class of UINavigationController. Please let me know if you need more details and I will wrote an answer for it

Comment: class LoginController: UIViewController

Comment: preferredStatusBarStyle is a method from UINavigationview controller not uiviewController it should be  
class LoginController: UINavigationViewController

Comment: If I change it that gives me 6 errors instead of 1 now :) In the tutorial he has class LoginController: UIViewController and it works for him.

Comment: Can you let me know the tutorial link to take a look on it?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWSc0wHFTXM 13:00min in

Comment: the answer below is the correct one ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you defining your `extension UIColor`? Are these two `preferredStatusBarStyle()` and `extension UIColor` within same class? I could see so, `extensions` should be outside of your class definition. Like below:

```
class LoginController: UIViewController {

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
       return .lightContent
    }
    //..other methods
}

extension UIColor{

    convenience init (r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

In iOS 10, [preferredStatusBarStyle](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621416-preferredstatusbarstyle) is a property, not a method. So instead of overriding it with a `func` declaration as you've done already, you `override` the `getter` with a `var` declaration like above.

Comment: like out the {} of the class LoginController: UIViewController ?

Comment: Ok thank you that solved the extension, but still having problems with the status bar

Comment: Updated in my answer, check it.

Comment: Thank so so much! man you two have made me not afraid to ask questions on here... the first few i posted were really dumb and like spelling errors. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Where is the button to mark it as answered? sorry that is probably a dumb question.

Comment: You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image).